# Is there any way to auto-update a Void and PlaceHolder without reloading the whole page?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net, void

I wounder if there is any way to auto-update a Void/PlaceHolder with some SQL queries without refreshing the whole ASP page?

I have tried with some ASP timer without any success.

**SOLUTION:**

I've tried more with `asp:updatapanel` and found a solution for my case.

ASP:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
    <ContentTemplate>
        //Content here
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID = "MachineBoxHolder" runat="server" /> 
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="2000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick">
</asp:Timer>
```

C#

```
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //content
    }
```

Comment: If you connect with HttpWebRequest there is no view to update so it is quicker than a connection that contains a view.  Most of the delays occur when refreshing a view.  if you are just sending data with no view you can speed up the transaction.

Comment: If this question gets reopened, you can post an answer here that describes your solution.

Comment: @jkdev Dont think i can answer at my own posts? Tell me if iam wrong.

Comment: You're allowed to ask a question, post your solution as an answer, and then click the checkmark to accept your answer. I've done that for some of my own questions (for example "How to write a file or data to an S3 object using boto3") and it's the standard procedure for sharing a solution that you've found.

Comment: Anyway, it looks like this question was reopened. It's possible to post answers now.

Comment: After 48 hours you can accept your own answer. Details: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

I found the solution this way.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
    <ContentTemplate>
        //Content here
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID = "MachineBoxHolder" runat="server" /> 
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="2000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick">
</asp:Timer>
```

C

```
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //content
}
```